# Sqoop Oracle Export Very slow

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I recently started working on `sqoop - hive/hadoop` on Linux. I have to import hive data from one table to oracle table. I am using simple `sqoop` export to do this. I have 6 million lines in hive table.

This command is giving me very poor performance and taking long time (85 minutes) to complete the job.

Query ->

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:db--username user --password password--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tb --table tb--columns 'col1,col2..col33'  --input-fields-terminated-by  ','  --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N'  -m 1
```

Is there any configuration change which can help me which can help to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without any additional information. I would suggest to start the export job again and monitor the environment to see where the bottle neck is (database? network? hadoop?). It might be also helpful to try [OraOop](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products/downloads-listing/connectors/quest.html) connector as it's usually faster.

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Is this a "wide" dataset? It might be a sqoop bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2920 if number of columns is very high (in hundreds), sqoop starts choking (very high on cpu).

When number of fields is small, it's usually other way around - when sqoop is bored and Oracle can't keep up. In this case we normally don't go over 45-55 mappers.